# Error when I install "passenger-install-nginx-module",but there is no any reaction. stop here

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Error when I install "passenger-install-nginx-module", but there is no any reaction. stop here. 
[image: pic1]

[image: pic2]

Answer (score 0):

Add Swap Space ref- https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-add-swap-space-on-ubuntu-16-04 and run the command again passenger-install-nginx-module